# Error installing package node-sass

Tags: npm

I always have same problem when installing node-sass

sudo npm install -g node-sass

*gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/max/Sites/xxxxxxx/node_modules/node-sass/build'*

I have update my node and npm version but the same nothing to do, it seems something with permission....  any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is due to a problem with installing [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) which is one of the dependencies.

It is due to the use of **sudo** while trying to install packages.

Read this https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions to see how to fix your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into permission issues. If you are installing `npm-packages` then it might possible that you are getting an `EACCES` error when trying to install a package globally. This means you do not have permission to write to the directories `npm` uses to store global packages and commands.

You can change the directory permissions by running commands: `sudo chmod u+x -R 775 ~/.npm` and `sudo chown $USER -R ~/.npm` or you can just run any `npm` command with `sudo`, that should get resolve your issue.

If you are installing an `npm-package` locally, then you should be in your local project directory and can try running `sudo npm install <pkg-name>` command to install required package. the purpose of using `sudo` is that it will change your owner permissions so you can make your current user authorized to run `npm` commands.

I'd recommend you to take a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you run `sudo npm install -g node-sass --unsafe-perm` should fix your issue.